# Carbon Monoxide

Tags: safety

Is it a law that every house/apartment has to have a carbon monoxide detector as well as a smoke detector? I live in an older apartment complex and am worried that I need to go get my own detector.

Comment: It depends on where you are.  You need to check your _local_ safety codes (or at least include a location in your question).

Comment: How is this related to Parenting?

Comment: @Dave Not so much as a parent, but as a big fan of having enough oxygen to breath, I rather like CO detectors. As a parent, I hope to pass on my love of oxygen to my daughters, like how my father passed down the love of classic rock to me.

Comment: @Brian - the fact that the word *local* was used in your comment indicates that instead of including a location, the question should be closed as *too localized*.

Comment: @corsiKa: Your argument does not convince me that this question is on topic.

Comment: I like having enough food to live, but that doesn't make questions about cooking on topic for parenting.se.  I'm going to close this as off-topic, but I'll ask the moderators at DIY if this would be on-topic there. If so, we'll migrate it.

Comment: I checked, and this is too localized for it to be a good fit for DIY.

Answer (score 4):

Laws on this kind of thing differ not only from country to country but from state to state, so ask your local council.

That said, if you use gas for cooking or for heating, a carbon monoxide detector is a really good idea. It is cheap, the batteries typically last for five or ten years, and it can **stop you and your  family dying in your sleep!**

Get one fitted because you should, not because you have to.